# Converting a PDF file to .json file on Mac

Tags: json, pdf

I have a PDF file for a map that I would like to convert into a .json file. I know there exists a conversion library for Windows and Linux (pdf2json) but I'm wondering if there is anyway I can convert it to a .json file on a Mac. Is it possible to do so? If so, how would I be able to?

Comment: You can convert it into XML then from XML you can easily convert it to json, or go through this https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any software I could use to convert the .pdf file into XML?

Comment: Yes there are many software's online available for converting to xml. Please google it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json but fist make sure you had nodejs installed on your Mac.